# セッション共有（？）の実現方法

Tags: javascript, php, apache, laravel-5

Laravelを勉強中で、セッション共有しようと色々試したのですが、共有できずに困っています。
2つの問題が重なっている（？）のかちょっとわからず混乱してしまっており、教えてほしいです。

1つのサーバ内にサブドメインで分けた複数のアプリが有り、その全てでセッション共有をしようと思っています。

```
directory/
    + sub1.myhost.test (Laravel5.1が入っています)
    + sub2.myhost.test (ここもLaravel5.1が入っています)
    + sub3.myhost.test (ここにもLaravel5.1が入っています)
    + sub4.myhost.test (ここにもLaravel5.1が入っています)
    + session (sessionファイルをここに保存しようと思います)
```

（Laravelのサブドメインルーティングというのがあったのですが、それぞれの規模と内容が異なるため、別アプリにする方針ということで決定しました。無理であれば変更もやむを得ません。）

設定しているのは
`/config/session.php`

```
'driver' => 'file',
'files' => base_path('../session'), 
'domain' => '.myhost.test',
```

`/.env`

```
APP_KEY=XXXX これを全てのアプリで同一にする
```

これらを設定しています。

例えば、sub2からsub1に対してajaxでPUTメソッドでリクエストを投げ
（プリフライトリクエストがかかる為、.htaccessにて下記を設定しています。）

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,DELETE
```

`request()->session()`メソッドの返り値`Illuminate\Session\Store`のIDを見るとリクエストのたびに変化してしまっています。ここが問題かなと思いつつも、どうすればよいかわからず、ご回答頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

問題はクロスドメインでAjax通信を行っていることではないでしょうか。

クロスドメインのAjax通信でCookieを送信するためには、以下の全てを満たす必要があります。

- リクエストを受ける側で `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` を送信する
- 上記ヘッダと `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` は併用できないため、オリジンを明示する。
  <sub>※複数のオリジンを列挙することはできないので、毎回アクセス元の Origin を出力することになります。</sub>
- Ajaxリクエストを送る側では、XMLHttpRequest の `withCredentials` を設定

参考

- [CORSリクエストでクレデンシャル(≒クッキー)を必要とする場合の注意点 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/kawaz/items/1e51c374b7a13c21b7e2)
- [HTTP アクセス制御 (CORS) | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials)

Comment: 試したところ完璧な動作が確認出来ました！クロスドメインのAjax通信に関して知らなかったため大変助かりました！ありがとうございます！